# Access SharePoint site's lists via Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Trying the basic example in the Graph Explorer. I am working against the beta API, but I assume this should be working per the documentation.

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/root` and I get back

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#sites/$entity",
    "createdDateTime": "2016-10-11T21:54:40.16Z",
    "description": "",
    "id": "contoso.sharepoint.com,11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111,11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-06-14T20:03:19Z",
    "name": "",
    "webUrl": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com",
    "root": {},
    "siteCollection": {
        "hostname": "contoso.sharepoint.com"
    },
    "displayName": "The Site"
}
```

Great I get my site, but I don't see Lists as expected from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/site

When trying `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/root/lists` or  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root?expand=lists` I get

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "unauthenticated",
        "message": "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "ded1ecbe-9664-4a29-9f8b-3278aeebc6d0",
            "date": "2017-06-14T20:33:35"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

And I check permissions and from what I can tell I have the necessary permissions.
[image]

Comment: Can you please try again? This (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/root/lists) seems to be working now.

Comment: perhaps you need an admin to accept those changes, since you do everything right